# SQL - Find duplicates with equivalencies

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around developing this SQL query.  Given the following two tables:

- ACADEMIC_HISTORY ( STUDENT_ID, TERM, COURSE_ID, COURSE_GRADE )
- COURSE_EQUIVALENCIES ( COURSE_ID, COURSE_ID_EQUIVALENT )

What would be the best way to detect if students have taken the same (***or an equivalent***) course in the past with a passing grade (C or better)?

### Example

Student #1 took the course ABC001 and received a grade of C. Ten years later, the course was renamed ABC011 and the appropriate entry was made in COURSE_EQUIVALENCIES.  The student retook the course under this new name and received a grade of B.  How can I construct a SQL query that will detect the duplicate courses and only count the first passing grade?

(The actual case is significantly more complicated, but this should get me started.)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
It's not even necessary to keep or discard any information. A query that simply shows classes with duplicates will be sufficient.

Comment: Are you maintaining any data for renaming changes?

Comment: Are there equivalence records for courses mapping to themselves (e.g. would there be a record in COURSE_EQUIVALENCIES that said course 100 was equivalent to itself?)

Comment: I think, All renames should be considered as different but equivalent courses, the fact that they are same is irrelevant

Comment: Also, do you need to worry about multiple levels in the heirarchy?   For example, course 100 is equiv. to course 200 and course 200 is equiv to course 300, therefore 100 is equiv to 300.

Comment: Courses are not mapped to themselves. There is only a single-level hierarchy.

Comment: Without a date, there is no first or last. If there are "equivalence duplicates" , which one do you want to keep?

Comment: Sorry. ACADEMIC_HISTORY also contains a field, TERM, that contains the term ID of the term when the course was taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like:

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT_ID
    ,MIN (COURSE_GRADE)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM         
        ACADEMIC_HISTORY 
    WHERE COURSE_ID =1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        h.STUDENT_ID
        ,h2.COURSE_ID
        ,h2.COURSE_GRADE
    FROM
    ACADEMIC_HISTORY AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COURSE_EQUIVELANCIES as e
        ON e.COURSE_ID = h.COURSE_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACADEMIC_HISTORY as h2
        ON h.STUDENT_ID = h2.STUDENT_ID
        AND h2.COURSE_ID = e.COURSE_ID_EQUIVELANT
    WHERE
         h.COURSE_ID =1
) AS t
WHERE STUDENT_ID =1
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d608f/20

Sorry posted with a bug.. it preferred the score of the actual course requested over any equivalencies - fixed now

this only looks for one level of equivalencies.. but maybe you want to enforce that and have that part of the data entry process.. review all possible equivalencies and enter the valid ones

EDIT: for first pass of qualifying course (using numbered terms..)

```
SELECT TOP 1
    STUDENT_ID
    ,MIN (COURSE_GRADE)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM         
        ACADEMIC_HISTORY 
    WHERE COURSE_ID =1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        h.STUDENT_ID
        ,h2.COURSE_ID
        ,h2.TERM
        ,h2.COURSE_GRADE
    FROM
    ACADEMIC_HISTORY AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COURSE_EQUIVELANCIES as e
        ON e.COURSE_ID = h.COURSE_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACADEMIC_HISTORY as h2
        ON h.STUDENT_ID = h2.STUDENT_ID
        AND h2.COURSE_ID = e.COURSE_ID_EQUIVELANT
    WHERE
         h.COURSE_ID =1
) AS t
WHERE STUDENT_ID =1

GROUP BY STUDENT_ID, TERM
ORDER BY TERM ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdded/6

(note TOP is a t-sql command for MySQL you need LIMIT)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I could be wrong, but isn't the above taking the lowest grade received for a given course (including dependencies)? I need to take the first passing grade for the course, chronologically speaking. (The table ACADEMIC_HISTORY also has a field, TERM, containing the term in which the course was taken.)

Comment: I'll update it for that.. any other different ways you need to look at it?  - ALSO NOTE, lowest here means highest ;-)

Comment: I've been tinkering with your code, but the problem is that the student IDs / course IDs are not constant. There are thousands of students and courses, so rerunning the query for each student ID and course ID combination is not feasible.

Comment: so take out the where clauses?  what is it that you are trying to do and what is the structure of any other tables involced.. for example are you looking for all courses available for student.. all students qualified for a course or what? each may be done in a different way, sometimes a union fits sometimes left outer join

Answer (score 0):

The data (in LOWERCASE)

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp;
SET search_path='tmp';

CREATE TABLE academic_history
        ( student_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , course_id CHAR(6)
        , course_grade CHAR(1)
        , PRIMARY KEY(student_id,course_id)
        );
INSERT INTO academic_history ( student_id,course_id,course_grade) VALUES
 (1, 'ABC001' , 'C' )
 , (1, 'ABC011' , 'B' )
 , (2, 'ABC011' , 'A' )
        ;

CREATE TABLE course_equivalencies
        ( course_id CHAR(6)
        , course_id_equivalent  CHAR(6)
        );
INSERT INTO course_equivalencies(course_id,course_id_equivalent) VALUES
        ( 'ABC011' , 'ABC001' )
        ;
```

The query:

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH canon AS (
        SELECT ah.student_id AS student_id
        , ah.course_id AS course_id
        , COALESCE (eq.course_id_equivalent,ah.course_id) AS course_id_equivalent
        FROM academic_history ah
        LEFT JOIN course_equivalencies eq ON eq.course_id = ah.course_id
        )
SELECT h.student_id
        , c.course_id_equivalent
        , MIN(h.course_grade) AS the_grade
FROM academic_history h
JOIN canon c ON c.student_id = h.student_id AND c.course_id = h.course_id
GROUP BY h.student_id, c.course_id_equivalent
ORDER BY h.student_id, c.course_id_equivalent
        ;
```

The output:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 2 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to table tmp.academic_history
drop cascades to table tmp.course_equivalencies
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "academic_history_pkey" for table "academic_history"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
 student_id | course_id_equivalent | the_grade 
------------+----------------------+-----------
          1 | ABC001               | B
          2 | ABC001               | A
(2 rows)
```